# Blowfish php in C?

Tags: php, c++, c, encryption, blowfish

Some people can register themselves on my website. For the password, I used this :

```
$key = "thisisasuperkey"; 
$key_crypted = md5($key); 
$pass = "thisisasuperpassword"; 
$pass_crypted = crypt($pass, '$2y$12$'.$key_crypted.'$');
```

This code return me something like that :

```
$2y$12$19ac9c3924183ab897f61uJr.j9b5cQ8NZS3rqMlNNUft9rEmtT5m
```

But now, I'm building a program in C/C++. I want that users enter in the program their username and password.

I test some of "example" on internet, but all "blowfish C" are returning something like that :

```
d00a0a19e5d7155ae6ac6e..........ce1072f5
```

Does someone have an idea where I can find the SAME blowfish in C/C++ (or the same in PHP)?

Comment: How about the PHP source code?

Comment: PHP code seams good to me (I tried to run it and it gave me the same result), I think his problem is linked to the fact he can't get the same results from PHP to C++

Comment: @jsn.crdnl Right. And what language is PHP written in, again? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say a word ^^ Are you suggesting to go into PHP's source code, extract the `crypt using blowfish` function and re-use it in his C/C++ application ?

Comment: @DaveRandom I don't get it. What are you trying to say ?

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/crypt.c#148

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll watch.

Comment: Note that Blowfish is a cryptographic algorithm that has been specified for specific binary inputs and outputs. As long as the bits are in the correct order, the input and output of Blowfish has been fully specified. It is probably more the API use and `crypt` implementation that you have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

[crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) is a function that shows up in glibc.  That said, bcrypt/blowfish based crypt implementation (identified with the string `$2a$` `$2x$` and `$2y$`) is not inlcuded in the mainline implementation.  Some linux/BSD distros add in support via a patch though, so that might be enough for you.

If not, you can check out [the source code](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/crypt/) for OpenBSD's crypt implementation, which will include support for bcrypt hashing. you can use that code to do what you want without too much trouble.

Comment: thank you for the answers, but I found my happiness in the PHP source code from DaveRandom message.

Thanks a lot.